# Yu-Gi-Oh! cards errata's release dates

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Is there a way to know exactly when a card has received an erratum?

There are some websites like yugipedia or yugioh wiki that collect card errata showing the first edition reprinted after a certain error, but the release date of those reprints isn't necessarily the date since the erratum is valid.

Cards like Firewall Dragon were reprinted some time after the last error and others like Darkness Approaches have never been reprinted since the last erratum.

Comment: *"but the release date of those reprints isn't necessarily the date since the erratum is valid."* - why not? why so sure got an example on why those sites may not be correct?... I was about to suggest the erratum at the bottom of yugioh wiki but seems that such place is not sufficient for you

Comment: https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Errata lists all errata... which ones you think are missing? I see https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Card_Errata:Firewall_Dragon missing...

Comment: @DarkCygnus I never stated those sites were incorrect. They are a great source of information and they have almost everything I want to know for a personal little project.
One of the very few missing things is the application date of a certain errata. They show an image of the first reprint after the errata but sometimes the release date of that reprint and the date of the errata application just doesn't match.
So here I am asking for some other source I could've missed

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to know exactly when a card has received an erratum?

You mentioned sites and wikis, and the one I find useful many many times is yugioh.fandom.com (https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Errata). Although I see that such page does *not* list Firewall Dragon for example (it's a wiki updated by nice folks giving free time anyways :).

I fear that it seems that such sites and wikis are the best option, as I browsed [Konami's page](https://yugiohblog.konami.com/articles/?p=7596) and it read "last updated 2016"... so even though they are the "canonical" source it seems they don't have the time (or don't care) about a complete list of errata...

May I suggest that if you see a card missing on those sites you could suggest and edit or include it perhaps? That way the site keeps updated and being useful.

Comment: Yeah I think waht you describe is the situation here in the TCG.
By doing a looot of research I finally found the official OCG [website](https://www.yugioh-card.com/japan/notice/revision/) that collect all the errata with the application dates.
Are the errata application dates the same to OCG and TCG?

Comment: @SteDeus Almost certain not, as most errata in the TCG have been issued to correct unsuitable translations.

Comment: @user10478 I see, thank you for the information! ^^

Comment: @SteDeus yep, TCG and OCG are two different games each with its own banlist, names, etc.. there are translation considerations between Japanese and English